# Arch Linux makepkg for AUR now always fails on finding dependencies

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

When trying to install something from AUR like I have done successful before with no issues, it now always fails.

```
[seth@archbang google-talkplugin-amd64]$ makepkg -si
==> Making package: google-talkplugin-amd64 2.5.6.0-1 (Mon Nov 21 19:26:58 MST 2011)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Installing missing dependencies...
error: target not found: error:
==> ERROR: 'pacman' failed to install missing dependencies.
```

I don't understand how to fix this error. It does this on others also when it was working.

ADDED:

pacman.conf

```
#
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

#
# GENERAL OPTIONS
#
[options]
# The following paths are commented out with their default values listed.
# If you wish to use different paths, uncomment and update the paths.
#RootDir     = /
#DBPath      = /var/lib/pacman/
#CacheDir    = /var/cache/pacman/pkg/
#LogFile     = /var/log/pacman.log
HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
# If upgrades are available for these packages they will be asked for first
SyncFirst   = pacman
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -C - %u > %o
#CleanMethod = KeepInstalled
Architecture = auto

# Pacman won't upgrade packages listed in IgnorePkg and members of IgnoreGroup
#IgnorePkg   =
#IgnoreGroup =

#NoUpgrade   =
#NoExtract   =

# Misc options (all disabled by default)
#UseSyslog
ShowSize
#UseDelta
TotalDownload
ILoveCandy

#
# REPOSITORIES
#   - can be defined here or included from another file
#   - pacman will search repositories in the order defined here
#   - local/custom mirrors can be added here or in separate files
#   - repositories listed first will take precedence when packages
#     have identical names, regardless of version number
#   - URLs will have $repo replaced by the name of the current repo
#   - URLs will have $arch replaced by the name of the architecture
#
# Repository entries are of the format:
#       [repo-name]
#       Server = ServerName
#       Include = IncludePath
#
# The header [repo-name] is crucial - it must be present and
# uncommented to enable the repo.
#

# The testing repositories are disabled by default. To enable, uncomment the
# repo name header and Include lines. You can add preferred servers immediately
# after the header, and they will be used before the default mirrors.

#[testing]
## Add your preferred servers here, they will be used first
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[core]
# Add your preferred servers here, they will be used first
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[extra]
# Add your preferred servers here, they will be used first
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

#[community-testing]
## Add your preferred servers here, they will be used first
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[multilib]
## Add your preferred servers here, they will be used first
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

[community]
# Add your preferred servers here, they will be used first
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist

# An example of a custom package repository.  See the pacman manpage for
# tips on creating your own repositories.
#[custom]
#Server = file:///home/custompkgs
```

MORE INFO:

```
[seth@archbang google-talkplugin-amd64]$ sudo makepkg --check --asroot
==> Making package: google-talkplugin-amd64 2.5.6.0-1 (Mon Nov 21 21:31:50 MST 2011)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Missing Dependencies:
  -> lib32-alsa-lib
  -> libstdc++5
  -> glew
  -> lib32-libxt
  -> lib32-openssl
  -> lib32-libxfixes
  -> lib32-gtk2
  -> lib32-gdk-pixbuf2
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> ERROR: Could not resolve all dependencies.
```

MAKEPGK.conf

```
#
# /etc/makepkg.conf
#

#########################################################################
# SOURCE ACQUISITION
#########################################################################
#
#-- The download utilities that makepkg should use to acquire sources
#  Format: 'protocol::agent'
DLAGENTS=('ftp::/usr/bin/wget -c --passive-ftp -t 3 --waitretry=3 -O %o %u'
          'http::/usr/bin/wget -c -t 3 --waitretry=3 -O %o %u'
          'https::/usr/bin/wget -c -t 3 --waitretry=3 --no-check-certificate -O %o %u'
          'rsync::/usr/bin/rsync -z %u %o'
          'scp::/usr/bin/scp -C %u %o')

# Other common tools:
# /usr/bin/snarf
# /usr/bin/lftpget -c
# /usr/bin/curl

#########################################################################
# ARCHITECTURE, COMPILE FLAGS
#########################################################################
#
CARCH="x86_64"
CHOST="x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

#-- Exclusive: will only run on x86_64
# -march (or -mcpu) builds exclusively for an architecture
# -mtune optimizes for an architecture, but builds for whole processor family
CFLAGS="-march=amdfam10 -mtune=amdfam10 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2"
CXXFLAGS="-march=amdfam10 -mtune=amdfam10 -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro,--hash-style=gnu"
#-- Make Flags: change this for DistCC/SMP systems
#MAKEFLAGS="-j5"

#########################################################################
# BUILD ENVIRONMENT
#########################################################################
#
# Defaults: BUILDENV=(fakeroot !distcc color !ccache check)
#  A negated environment option will do the opposite of the comments below.
#
#-- fakeroot: Allow building packages as a non-root user
#-- distcc:   Use the Distributed C/C++/ObjC compiler
#-- color:    Colorize output messages
#-- ccache:   Use ccache to cache compilation
#-- check:    Run the check() function if present in the PKGBUILD
#
BUILDENV=(fakeroot !distcc color !ccache check)
#
#-- If using DistCC, your MAKEFLAGS will also need modification. In addition,
#-- specify a space-delimited list of hosts running in the DistCC cluster.
#DISTCC_HOSTS=""

#########################################################################
# GLOBAL PACKAGE OPTIONS
#   These are default values for the options=() settings
#########################################################################
#
# Default: OPTIONS=(strip docs libtool emptydirs zipman purge)
#  A negated option will do the opposite of the comments below.
#
#-- strip:     Strip symbols from binaries/libraries
#-- docs:      Save doc directories specified by DOC_DIRS
#-- libtool:   Leave libtool (.la) files in packages
#-- emptydirs: Leave empty directories in packages
#-- zipman:    Compress manual (man and info) pages in MAN_DIRS with gzip
#-- purge:     Remove files specified by PURGE_TARGETS
#
OPTIONS=(strip docs libtool emptydirs zipman purge)

#-- File integrity checks to use. Valid: md5, sha1, sha256, sha384, sha512
INTEGRITY_CHECK=(md5)
#-- Options to be used when stripping binaries. See `man strip' for details.
STRIP_BINARIES="--strip-all"
#-- Options to be used when stripping shared libraries. See `man strip' for details.
STRIP_SHARED="--strip-unneeded"
#-- Options to be used when stripping static libraries. See `man strip' for details.
STRIP_STATIC="--strip-debug"
#-- Manual (man and info) directories to compress (if zipman is specified)
MAN_DIRS=({usr{,/local}{,/share},opt/*}/{man,info})
#-- Doc directories to remove (if !docs is specified)
DOC_DIRS=(usr/{,local/}{,share/}{doc,gtk-doc} opt/*/{doc,gtk-doc})
#-- Files to be removed from all packages (if purge is specified)
PURGE_TARGETS=(usr/{,share}/info/dir .packlist *.pod)

#########################################################################
# PACKAGE OUTPUT
#########################################################################
#
# Default: put built package and cached source in build directory
#
#-- Destination: specify a fixed directory where all packages will be placed
#PKGDEST=/home/packages
#-- Source cache: specify a fixed directory where source files will be cached
#SRCDEST=/home/sources
#-- Source packages: specify a fixed directory where all src packages will be placed
#SRCPKGDEST=/home/srcpackages
#-- Packager: name/email of the person or organization building packages
#PACKAGER="John Doe <john@doe.com>"

#########################################################################
# EXTENSION DEFAULTS
#########################################################################
#
# WARNING: Do NOT modify these variables unless you know what you are
#          doing.
#
PKGEXT='.pkg.tar.xz'
SRCEXT='.src.tar.gz'

# vim: set ft=sh ts=2 sw=2 et:
```

RESULTS

```
[seth@archbang ~]$ sudo pacman -Syu && sudo pacman -S base-devel
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core is up to date
 extra is up to date
 multilib is up to date
 community is up to date
:: Starting full system upgrade...
 there is nothing to do
:: There are 11 members in group base-devel:
:: Repository core
   1) autoconf  2) automake  3) bison  4) fakeroot  5) flex  6) gcc  7) libtool
   8) m4  9) make  10) patch  11) pkg-config

Enter a selection (default=all): 
warning: autoconf-2.68-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: automake-1.11.1-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: bison-2.5-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: fakeroot-1.18.1-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: flex-2.5.35-5 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: gcc-4.6.2-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: libtool-2.4.2-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: m4-1.4.16-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: make-3.82-4 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: patch-2.6.1-3 is up to date -- reinstalling
warning: pkg-config-0.26-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Targets (11): m4-1.4.16-2 [0.16 MB]  autoconf-2.68-2 [0.56 MB]
              automake-1.11.1-3 [0.51 MB]  bison-2.5-2 [0.42 MB]
              fakeroot-1.18.1-1 [0.05 MB]  flex-2.5.35-5 [0.24 MB]
              gcc-4.6.2-1 [17.03 MB]  libtool-2.4.2-2 [0.26 MB]
              make-3.82-4 [0.34 MB]  patch-2.6.1-3 [0.06 MB]
              pkg-config-0.26-2 [0.03 MB]

Total Download Size:    0.00 MB
Total Installed Size:   77.21 MB

Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(11/11) checking package integrity                 [----------------------] 100%
(11/11) checking for file conflicts                [----------------------] 100%
( 1/11) upgrading m4                               [----------------------] 100%
( 2/11) upgrading autoconf                         [----------------------] 100%
( 3/11) upgrading automake                         [----------------------] 100%
( 4/11) upgrading bison                            [----------------------] 100%
( 5/11) upgrading fakeroot                         [----------------------] 100%
( 6/11) upgrading flex                             [----------------------] 100%
( 7/11) upgrading gcc                              [----------------------] 100%
( 8/11) upgrading libtool                          [----------------------] 100%
( 9/11) upgrading make                             [----------------------] 100%
(10/11) upgrading patch                            [----------------------] 100%
(11/11) upgrading pkg-config                       [----------------------] 100%
[seth@archbang ~]$ sudo pacman -Qi base-devel
error: package "base-devel" not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the dependencies for this application are 32-bit. In order for pacman to be able to install them, you need to enable the multilib repo in your `pacman.conf` to successfully build the package.

See [the multilib entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Official_Repositories#.5Bmultilib.5D) on the Arch Wiki.

If that doesn't work, you should try installing one (or more) or the dependencies with `pacman -S $pkg` to ensure that your pacman database is up-to-date and that you are synching to a current mirror.

As Arch is a rolling release, it is *critical* that you sync to a current mirror - otherwise this will cause all sorts of issues.

If that works, then I would suggest checking your `makepkg.conf` for any anomalies.

**Update**
You have to build some of the dependencies by hand: `libpng12` and `openssl-compatibility`, eg. I have no idea why makepkg isn't printing out the complete error message: it should read:

```
==> Making package: google-talkplugin 2.5.6.0-1 (Wed Nov 23 18:58:38 NZDT 2011)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Installing missing dependencies...
error: target not found: openssl-compatibility
==> ERROR: 'pacman' failed to install missing dependencies.
```

You could also look at using an AUR helper to automatically install dependencies from the AUR.

Comment: Yes this is already enabled, this happens with packages that have no 32-bit deps

Comment: I don't understand this 'error: target not found: error:'

Comment: Please update your question with details about how you are trying to build the package. Also, is that the complete error message? You could also try this PKGBUILD to see if you get the same error https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=40056

Comment: I am not sure what more I can give, I extract the tarball, run makepgk as I show up there. And yes that is the exact error I get and the same with that PKGBUILD you posted. The error just says that... error

Comment: I have current mirrors from the Arch Linux Mirror Generator. I have posted pacman.conf and makepkg.conf. Thank you for your extended help on this problem.

Comment: Assuming that you have tried installing some of the dependencies using pacman (and succeeded), then I am stumped. What is the output of `pacman -Qi base-devel`?

Comment: That is odd.... it gives error not found, but they are already installed

Comment: You can't use `makepkg` without installing `base-devel`. Install that and you are good to go...

Comment: I mean to say that they are installed, but -Qi says it can not find them....

Comment: Then they are *not* installed. You are mistaking `base` for `base-devel`. Do a `pacman -Syu && pacman -S base-devel`, build your package (and accept my answer).

Comment: Added the results, I did mention I had built PKGBUILDS before.

Comment: My bad: I meant `-Qg`. Built it myself: see update.

Comment: Hate to be a pain, but I have already hand built and installed those two as I had to do for Chrome. I still get the same error... of nothing

Comment: It's not just those two: it's all of the dependencies in the PKGBUILD that are AUR packages... That's why I suggested an AUR helper to automate the process. No idea why your makepkg is broken and not printing the failed package. Sorry.

Comment: @jasonwryan, it seems unlikely, but could this `makepkg` oddness be due to some customization made by ArchBang?

Comment: @HalosGhost I don't know. I can't imagine why they would want to fool around with `makepkg`. I think it more likely it is something that the OP had done.

Comment: Don't forget to run `pacman -Sy` to refresh the package database after adding the **`multilib`** repo.